# Create Bi-weekly Variable Based On A Custom Start-date

Tags: python

I've done some light searching using "get biweekly variable in python" but havent been able to find many useful posts so I thought to post my question here.

I have a dataframe with tens of thousands of records. The dataframe contains records for the entire fiscal year. Each records has a datetime variable `CHECKIN_DATE_TIME`. I would like to create a biweekly variable beginning with the date June 30 2019.

```
ID       CHECKIN_DATE_TIME
1       2019-06-30 13:36:00
2       2019-06-30 14:26:00
3       2019-06-30 20:10:00
4       2019-06-30 21:27:00
....
51       2019-07-10 13:36:00
52       2019-07-10 10:26:00
53       2019-07-10 10:10:00
54       2019-07-10 23:27:00
....
```

I would like a new dataframe to look like this where 6/30/2019 - 7/13/2019 would be week 1, 7/14/2019 to 7/27/2019 would be week 2, and so on until the end date of 6/28/2020. Thus there will be 26 weeks within the `Week` variable and each week represent a 2 week time frame.

EDIT and to have the last day in the week range assigned to the week number.

```
ID       CHECKIN_DATE_TIME       Week    Date
1       2019-06-30 13:36:00       1     7/13/2019
2       2019-06-30 14:26:00       1     7/13/2019
3       2019-06-30 20:10:00       1     7/13/2019
4       2019-06-30 21:27:00       1     7/13/2019
....
51       2019-07-20 13:36:00      2     7/27/2019
52       2019-07-20 10:26:00      2     7/27/2019
53       2019-07-20 10:10:00      2     7/27/2019
54       2019-07-20 23:27:00      2
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do so by determining the number of days between the check-in date and 2019-06-30 and then doing a floor division by 14.

```
df['CHECKIN_DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df.CHECKIN_DATE_TIME)    
df['week'] = (df.CHECKIN_DATE_TIME - pd.datetime(2019, 6, 30)).dt.days // 14 + 1
df['last_week_day'] = (pd.to_timedelta(-((df.CHECKIN_DATE_TIME - pd.datetime(2019,6,30)).dt.days % 14) + 13 ,'d') + df.CHECKIN_DATE_TIME).dt.date

# note I've created my own test set.

   ID   CHECKIN_DATE_TIME  week last_week_day
0   1 2019-06-30 13:36:00     1    2019-07-13
1   2 2019-07-10 10:36:00     1    2019-07-13
2   3 2019-07-12 02:36:00     1    2019-07-13
3   4 2019-07-18 18:36:00     2    2019-07-27
4   5 2019-07-30 11:36:00     3    2019-08-10
5   6 2019-08-01 20:36:00     3    2019-08-10
```

Edit: added `last_week_day` as per request in comments. This is done by calculating the required number of days to the `CHECKIN_DATE_TIME` columns using modulo operator `%`.

Comment: thank you but this produces the following error "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'"

Comment: Ah I assumed CHECKIN_DATE_TIME was of type datetime, I've updated the answer to cast it to the proper type.

Comment: this works but one last error warning associated with the date-time conversion: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Most likely you made a slice of the original dataframe before you are running this code, this is not something related to the current question. It is also just a warning, for its possible impacts  and solutions see: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Comment: thank you super helpful and informative - one other question that may warrant another post but what if I wanted to create a new column/variable that contains the last date in each week category. So for example, for week 1 the " new date" column would read 7/13/2019, for week 2 the new date column would read 7/27/2019.

Comment: Adjusted the answer with this request, you might want to simplify the oneliner a bit for readabilty if you'll use this in a shared environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217021/discussion-between-raven-and-scootcork).

Answer (score 2):

Using Pandas date_range function it is very easy and efficient way to generate date list for weekly, bi-weekly or monthly

```
import pandas as pd
from  datetime import date,datetime,timedelta

date_rng=pd.date_range(start=date.today()-timedelta(weeks=53),end=date.today(), freq="2W-SAT")
for i in date_rng: 
  print(i)
```